# C++ weak_ptr.lock() segfault

Tags: c++, qt, weak-references

So I have this function to add listeners and it converts shared pointers of a class so that I can call it later when I get a notification.

```
void registerListener(std::shared_ptr<T> listener)
{
    if (!listener) {
        qCWarning(OBSERVER_LOGGER) << "Attempted to register a null observer.";
        return;
    }
    // TODO make a foreach function that removes dead listeners to get rid of this code dupe
    for (auto iter=listeners.begin(); iter != listeners.end(); ) {
        if (auto shared = iter->lock()) {
            if (listener == shared) {
                return;
            }
            iter++;
        } else {
            iter = listeners.erase(iter);
        }
    }
    auto weak = std::weak_ptr<T>(listener);
    listeners.push_back(weak);
}

void notify(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<T>)> onNotify)
{
    // TODO make a foreach function that removes dead listeners to get rid of this code dupe
    for (auto iter=listeners.begin(); iter != listeners.end(); ) {
        if (auto shared = iter->lock()) {
            onNotify(shared);
            iter++;
        } else {
            iter = listeners.erase(iter);
        }
    }
}

private:
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<T>> listeners;
```

and for some reason, "iter->lock()" segfaults. I will say that this is a Qt application, but I have purposely not created ANY threads (that I know of) so I am just super confused what I am doing wrong to make these weak_ptrs break. So if I run it in gdb, it works just fine. But if I set, "set disable-randomization off" then I get the error. So I feel like this is some weird problem where with uninitialized variables. If it helps, this is the stack when I crash in gdb.

```
#0  0x00007f856bd8beec in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_get_use_count() const ()
#1  0x00007f856bd844a8 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_add_ref_lock_nothrow() ()
#2  0x00007f856bd9cd7d in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count(std::__weak_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&, std::nothrow_t) ()
#3  0x00007f856bda9948 in std::__shared_ptr<IEntityListener<Assignment>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr(std::__weak_ptr<IEntityListener<Assignment>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&, std::nothrow_t) ()
#4  0x00007f856bda8a62 in std::shared_ptr<IEntityListener<Assignment> >::shared_ptr(std::weak_ptr<IEntityListener<Assignment> > const&, std::nothrow_t) ()
#5  0x00007f856bda701a in std::weak_ptr<IEntityListener<Assignment> >::lock() const ()
#6  0x00007f856bda5624 in Observer<IEntityListener<Assignment> >::notify(std::function<void (std::shared_ptr<IEntityListener<Assignment> >)>) ()
#7  0x00007f856bda3a1a in EntityObserver<Assignment>::notifyCreated(std::shared_ptr<Assignment>) ()
```

EDIT: Michael Burr posted the possibility of listeners getting registered while new listeners where being added, which could totally happen. This would cause the iterator to be invalid, and when I go to call weak_ptr.lock() on a section of memory that isn't a weak_ptr, BOOM. I think there is a moral in here somewhere I just have to find it.

Comment: Can you give us a complete minimal working program with a main()?

Comment: You could simplify `auto weak = std::weak_ptr<T>(listener);` to `std::weak_ptr<T> weak(listener);`.  Also it's *very* confusing how you have a function called `notify()` which takes an argument by the same name--which is also a function!

Comment: I can try to later I don't actually have a simpler program that crashes yet. The thing that makes no sense, is that for the past 6 months this worked, and then I added a new listener and BOOM suddenly everything explodes. But I even went so far as to diff the new listener and its EXACTLY THE SAME!

Comment: @JohnZwinck I will totally admit I never noticed the name dupe before. Let me fix that.

Comment: The crash may not even be in this code. Other parts of your code could have been trampling on the data used by the shared/weak_ptrs or the vector etc.

Comment: You should try running your program under valgrind (or your platform's equivalent) to check for memory access errors.  It may be that the real problem is outside the code you have shown us, or at least on a different line from where it finally crashes.

Comment: @John Zwinck should I post the output of valgrind it to something like gist?

Comment: If valgrind shows you errors you should try to fix them.  If you can't fix them, post the errors into the question itself.

Comment: @JohnZwinck So I am looking at this valgrind output and I see a whole lot of "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)", but these are all in some libraries I use. I guess I should look up if there is a way to say only look in this ".o" file to filter those out?

Comment: Read about creating valgrind suppression files.   You can exclude certain things if you *know for sure* they are harmless.  Which, by the way, they probably are not.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I did find a weird message about deallocating with the weak_ptr

Comment: What is the type of your listener? Pointer to some interface class or a std::function<>? I mean that T in your shared_ptr<T> ...

Comment: @user2225104 T = an interface "IEntityListener<Assignment>" in this particular section

Comment: OMG I am so sorry I wasted everyones time. I am glad that JohnZwinck told me about valgrind. I will post the problem.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest - could you also run clang analyzer over it, please? I wonder if static code checker would have found the issue, too.

Comment: Nope I spoke to soon wtf am I doing wrong. @user2225104 I will fire up my mac and move my code and try to do a clang analyzer on it too.

Comment: You said the last change you did was to add a new listener. Typically the newest code is the prime suspect. Maybe your listener was not instantiated as a shared_ptr but simply with new or something trivial like that.

Comment: Just wondering, Boost's weak_ptr had an `expired()` method that could be used to check whether the ref was still valid, doesn't the standard weak_ptr have that? Point is that if you actually create a shared_ptr, it means an increment and lateron a decrement just for checking if the refcount is zero. These operations can take several dozen cycles when done in a thread-safe way!

Comment: Standard now forces you to first get a shared_ptr<> before you can use the content of the weak_ptr. The expired version of boost is probably worse, as it could introduce race conditions. ``if(!wp.expired) { wp->Use(); // race! }``

Comment: I think you misunderstand the use of the `expired()`, @user2225104 and it also doesn't imply that there is a also an overloaded `operator->`. Instead, `expired()` can be used to check if the `weak_ptr` still refers to an object or not. This does not imply a race condition, because once the refcount reaches zero, it will never become nonzero again! So if `expired()` returns true, you know that it will remain expired without a race condition. The opposite, i.e. that if `expired()` returns false you can assume that it still refers to an object is obviously not true, but I never claimed that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This /is/ the definition of a race condition. I gave the stereotypical code to demonstrate that. ``if(!wp.expired()) { Use(wp); }`` If you ever check like that (use that expired() function for existence testing) you have a race condition as it is not messing with the reference counts in any way. So even the next machine instruction later, your check is null and void. It can be gone already. This is why ``std::shared_ptr<> p = wp.lock()`` is much better. It manipulates the reference counter (increments) if the wp was still valid at that time. -> thread safe.

Comment: Dear @user2225104, I'm aware that you have demonstrated that `expired()` can be used wrongly. Let me repeat, I never claimed that the examples you provided or any equivalent code are without race condition. However, I'm wondering, do you understand that it can also be used correctly and efficiently?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt An api which lays traps for a MAJOR use case is a bad API. Even though it is possible to avoid the traps.

Comment: As C++ programmer, you sometimes have responsibility shifted to you in order to maximize efficiency. See e.g. the containers/iterators/algorithms from the STL, where a bunch of things cause "undefined behaviour". Many of these cases are trivial but slow to catch, as demonstrated by the diagnostic mode of some stdlibs. Further, lock() can already return null, which must be checked (typical RTFM error), so your "MAJOR use case" is making redundant checks that are obvious races. BTW: Some research indicates that your claim is wrong that expired() didn't make it to the standard!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `notify()` is called is it possible that the function called through the `onNotify()` function object will result in `registerListener()` being called indirectly (or some other code that can add or remove entries in the `listeners` collection)?

If so, then the `iter` being used in the `notify()` `for` loop can be invalidated.  You might want to change `notify()` to look something like the following which queues up all the `shared_ptr` objects to notify so that it doesn't matter if the `listeners` collection is modified during any of the `onNotify()` callbacks:

```
#include <queue>

void notify(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<T>)> onNotify)
{
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T>> notify_targets;

    for (auto iter=listeners.begin(); iter != listeners.end(); ) {
        if (auto shared = iter->lock()) {
            notify_targets.push(shared);
            iter++;
        } else {
            iter = listeners.erase(iter);
        }
    }

    while (!notify_targets.empty()) {
        onNotify(notify_targets.front());
        notify_targets.pop();
    }

}
```

Comment: Such loops can also be prevented by making sure, Event listeners only get const pointers to the observable object along with registerListener() not being a const operation.

Comment: YES! This fixed it. I don't know why I didn't see that before. I feel like an idiot again. We had the exact same problem in an Android app too. Note to self invalidating a iter REALLY REALLY blows. I have been keeping this QML app entirely async isntead of multithreaded so I didn't think about the list being modified while notifying listeners.

Comment: @Buttink: it's a very easy thing to miss since the operation that invalidates the iterator is out of sight. It doesn't help matters that there are a slew of rules about when iterators are invalidated.  Anyway, MSVC has very good iterator validity tracking in their debug builds but sometimes the configuration of it can be confusing (search for `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` and `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`). I'm unaware of any similar iterator debugging support in GCC's toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find an obvious problem in the code you show. So I assume, the problem resides in the code you do not show. Bear in mind, that Q_OBJECT adorned objects also have a qt- related life cycle management. Maybe there is some interference...

Maybe it helps if you compare your code with the code I post here and you quickly find the crucial difference.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

template <typename _Observable>
class IObserver
{
public:
    virtual ~IObserver() {}
    virtual void OnChange(const _Observable* what) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class CObservable
    : public IObserver<T> // Make sure this class breaks once IObserver<> changes.
{
public:
    typedef IObserver<T> Observer_t;
    typedef std::weak_ptr<Observer_t> Observer_reference;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Observer_t> Observer_strong_reference;
    typedef T Class_t;
    typedef std::vector<Observer_reference> ObserverRefCollection;
private:

    ObserverRefCollection m_observers;

    void CleanupZombies()
    {
        m_observers.erase(std::remove_if(m_observers.begin(), m_observers.end(),
            [this](Observer_reference iter) -> bool
        {
            Observer_strong_reference o = iter.lock();
            return !o;
        }
        ), m_observers.end());
    }
public:
    void RegisterObserver(Observer_strong_reference& observer)
    {
        if (!observer)
            return;
        for (auto& iter : m_observers)
        {
            if (observer == iter.lock())
                return;
        }
        m_observers.push_back(Observer_reference(observer));
    }

    /*virtual*/ void OnChange(const Class_t* what)
    {
        bool hasZombies = false;
        for (auto& iter : m_observers)
        {
            Observer_strong_reference o = iter.lock();
            if (o)
            {
                o->OnChange(what);
            }
            else
            {
                hasZombies = true;
            }
        }
        if (hasZombies)
            CleanupZombies();
    }
};

class CObservableUint32
    : public CObservable<CObservableUint32>
{
    uint32_t m_value;
public:
    void Set(uint32_t newValue)
    {
        bool changed = newValue != m_value;
        m_value = newValue;
        if (changed)
        {
            OnChange(this);
        }
    }
    uint32_t Get() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }
};

class CSomeObserver
    : public IObserver < CObservableUint32 >
{

public:
    CSomeObserver()
        : IObserver<CObservableUint32>()
    {

    }
    virtual ~CSomeObserver()
    {

    }
    virtual void OnChange(const CObservableUint32* what)
    {

    }
};
```

Somewhere else...

```
    CObservableUint32 observable;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<IObserver<CObservableUint32> > observer = std::make_shared<CSomeObserver>();
        observable.RegisterObserver(observer);
        observable.Set(42UL);
    }
    observable.Set(100);
```

Comment: I factored out the reusable part to class CObservable. This allows for people to re-use the pattern shown here. Please do not edit that away.